# Were Tolkien's Ents inspired by Blackwood's "The Man Whom the Trees Loved"?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, inspiration, ents

Reading '[*The Man Whom the Trees Loved*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2916266-the-man-whom-the-trees-loved)' by Algernon Blackwood, I find myself wondering if this is a case of parallel evolution, or whether JRRT was influenced by this material in working up the Ents. Are there any notes that indicate that he was aware of this story?

Comment: I was about to answer your question with "Trees", but...

Comment: Treebeard is said to be in part based on Tolkiens good friend C.S. Lewis.
http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Treebeard
http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Treebeard

Comment: The edit to the title is a bit of a distraction.

Comment: Anecdotally there are various trees around oxford that are said to have been inspiration for Ents. I have no idea how to go about finding canonical evidence for this though. An example is http://www.oxfordmail.co.uk/news/top_news/11376864.The_Ent_is_nigh_for_Tolkien_tree/?ref=mac but that just says "it is said to have influenced [his] work" rather than giving anything more canonical.

Comment: To some extent, they were inspired by Tolkien's scholar friends, the members of the Inklings, including C.S. Lewis.

Comment: I would interpret the Ents as more a general description of gender roles from the time. Mothers tend to the growing and nurturing and order of the household, while men are less attached to such things.

Comment: @bmargulies Agreed, and it's given rise to 'answers' which attempt to answer the title but not the actual question. I fixed it.

Comment: From the Wikipedia page: The word "Ent" was taken from the Anglo-Saxon (Old English) word ent, meaning "giant". Tolkien borrowed the word from the Anglo-Saxon phrases **orþanc enta geweorc** ("work of cunning giants") and **eald enta geweorc** ("old work of giants", which describes Roman ruins). In its Anglo-Saxon sense, the word "Ent" probably denotes the most ubiquitous of all creatures in fantasy and folklore (behind perhaps only dragons), for the word can refer to a variety of large, roughly humanoid creatures, such as giants, trolls, or even the monster Grendel from the poem Beowulf.

Comment: And of course, Treebeard the Ent was indeed a giant for part of the development of LotR!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is no mention of Algernon Blackwood in the *Letters*, and neither in the *HoME*, *Unfinished Tales* or *The Silmarillion*. Tolkien seems to suggest that the main inspiration for the Ents would've been George MacDonald's walking tree spirits (if there was any significant inspiration) with the idea of them going to war taken from Shakespeare's Macbeth. Shakespeare, however, did not inspire them as a character but motivated their actions (marching to war).

Tolkien himself was never sure of interpretations to his work, and "found it amusing" to find interpretations:

> The Lord of the Rings as a story was finished so long ago now that I can take a largely impersonal view of it, and find 'interpretations' quite amusing; even those that I might make myself, which are mostly post scriptum: I had very little particular, conscious, intellectual, intention in mind at any point.
>   <sub>The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien: Letter 163</sub>

This quote is followed by note 41 of the Letter (On the topic of Ents):

> **Their part in the story is due**, I think, to my bitter disappointment and disgust from schooldays with the shabby use made in Shakespeare of the coming of 'Great Birnam wood to high Dunsinane hill': **I longed to devise a setting in which the trees might really march to war.**
>   <sub>The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien: Letter 163, Note 41</sub>

This seems to suggest that in 1955, Tolkien was aware of the influence of Shakespeare's Macbeth on the storyline of the Ents, however does not credit Shakespeare with inspiring their invention.

From an unpublished letter dated 1958, Tolkien claimed that the Ents were "original" and describes their inspiration from his life, but admits to influences from George MacDonald's and again Shakespeare's Macbeth:

> Ents is also an ancient English word (for a giant); but the Ent of my world I suppose are entirely "original" creatures, so far as that can be said of any human work. If you like, they are a **mythological form taken by my life long love for trees**, with perhaps some remote influence from George MacDonald's *Phantastes* (a work I do not much like), and certainly a strong (twist?) given my deep disappointment with *Shakespeare's MacBeth*...
>   <sub>[From a letter to Mrs LM Cutts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3umU.png)
>
>   [In it's original form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs2RV.jpg)</sub>

In 1956 and again in 1963, Tolkien seems to suggest that his Ents simply came to him and that he had "no recollection of inventing" them. Suggesting that during the writing of Chapter IV of Book Three, the story created the characters itself. Although admitted to knowing that Frodo (even though it turned out to be Merry and Pippin) would have a tree-adventure.

> Thus, though I knew for years that Frodo would run into a tree-adventure somewhere far down the Great River, I have no recollection of inventing Ents. I came at last to the point, and wrote the 'Treebeard' chapter **without any recollection of any previous thought**: just as it now is. And then I saw that, of course, it had not happened to Frodo at all.
>   <sub>The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien: Letter 180</sub>

> There are or were no Ents in the older stories – because the Ents in fact only presented themselves to my sight, without premeditation or any previous conscious knowledge, when I came to Chapter IV of Book Three.
>   <sub>The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien: Letter 247</sub>

Comment: That's a very odd condemnation.  I always found Shakespeare's use of the trees a brilliantly ironic resolution to the "impossible" prophecy that kept Macbeth smugly secure in his castle.

Answer (score 30):

Tolkien himself described the process (or as much as he consciously can make of it) in a footnote to [Letter 163](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_163):

> Take the Ents, for instance. I did not consciously invent them at
>   all. The chapter called 'Treebeard', from Treebeard's first remark on
>   p. 66, was written off more or less as it stands, with an effect on my
>   self (except for labour pains) almost like reading some one else's
>   work. And I like Ents now because they do not seem to have anything to
>   do with me. I daresay something had been going on in the 'unconscious'
>   for some time, and that accounts for my feeling throughout, especially
>   when stuck, that I was not inventing but reporting (imperfectly) and
>   had at times to wait till 'what really happened' came through. But
>   looking back analytically I should say that Ents are composed of
>   philology, literature, and life. They owe their name to the *eald enta geweorc* of Anglo-Saxon, and their connexion with stone. Their part in
>   the story is due, I think, to my bitter disappointment and disgust
>   from schooldays with the shabby use made in Shakespeare of the coming
>   of 'Great Birnam wood to high Dunsinane hill': I longed to devise a
>   setting in which the trees might really march to war. And into this
>   has crept a mere piece of experience, the difference of the 'male' and
>   'female' attitude to wild things, the difference between unpossessive love and gardening.

So, probably not influenced by Algernon Blackwood, though possibly by Shakespeare.

Comment: Do you know what he means by "the difference of the 'male' and 'female' attitude to wild things, the difference between unpossessive love and gardening"? I would've said men tend to be *more* possessive, and the original gardener, Adam, was a man.

Comment: @MissMonicaE "But our hearts did not go on growing in the same way: the Ents gave their love to things that they met in the world, and the Entwives gave their thought to other things, for the
Ents loved the great trees; and the wild woods [...] But the Entwives gave their minds to the lesser trees, and
to the meads in the sunshine [...] They did not desire to speak with these
things; but they wished them to hear and obey what was said to them. [...] for the Entwives desired order, and plenty, and
peace (by which they meant that things should remain where they had set
them)."

Comment: I think the key thing you've misinterpreted is that Shakespeare isn't an inspiration behind his Ents. However and inspiration to the part they play in the tale. **"Their part in the story is due"**